# Why is my JavaScript array showing a two element count when there is supposed to be only one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an JS Array that is supposed to show only one element. It does, however its index is 1 rather than 0 and the count is 2. Also the array does not show a 0 index.

My code:

```
var _UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitData = [];
var rows = $('#jqxUOMRelatedUnitsDropdownGrid').jqxGrid('getrows');
var RecordCount = 0;

if (rows.length !== 1 && rows[0]["UOMRelatedUnit_Name"] !== ""){
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        var row = rows[i];
        var _row = {};
        if(row.UOMRelatedUnit_AddItem !== F) {
            RecordCount += 1;
            _row["Name"] = $("#txtUnitOfMeasureSetName").val();
            _row["Active"] = T;
            _row["UnitOfMeasureTypeID"] = $("input[type='radio'][id='rblUnitOfMeasureType']:checked").val();
            _row["BaseUnitID"] = $("input[type='radio'][id='rblUnitOfMeasureBaseUnit']:checked").val();
            _row["RelatedUnitDisplayOrder"] = RecordCount;
            _row["RelatedUnitName"] = row.UOMRelatedUnit_Name;
            _row["RelatedUnitAbbreviation"] = row.UOMRelatedUnit_Abbreviation;
            _row["RelatedUnitConversionRatio"] = row.UOMRelatedUnit_ConversionOfBaseUnits;
            _row["UnitOfMeasureSetID"] = UnitOfMeasureSetID;
            _UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitData[i] = _row;
        }
    }
....
}
```

In my JQx Grid, I have at least four choices. For this issue, Ive only selected the 2 choice in the Grid and its `AddItem` value is True, everything else is False.

What do I need to change in my logic as I can not see it at this point?

**EDIT 1**

I overlooked the placement of `RecordCount += 1;`, I will try moving it to the end of the assignments and see what happens.

**EDIT 2**

The placement made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain another variable for indexing your data like this

```
var index=0; // place this outside of for loop

_UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitData[index++] = _row;
```

you don't need  `RecordCount += 1;` .

you can get the rowscount by using `_UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitData.length`